# Comparing current row with previous row - leetcode solution

Tags: sql, join

I am trying to understand the solution to the following leetcode problem:
https://leetcode.com/problems/rising-temperature/

The solution given was as follows:

```
SELECT weather.id AS 'Id'
FROM weather
JOIN
weather w ON DATEDIFF(weather.date, w.date) = 1
AND weather.Temperature > w.Temperature;
```

The problem requires calculation of delta between the current row's temperature and previous temperature. How is this being achieved in the solution above? It looks like the comparison is being done between the same row of left and right tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the data in the table is in the form of one value per date, the previous temperature has a `RecordDate` value that is one day earlier, so to compare the values the table is `JOIN`ed to itself on that condition (i.e. `DATEDIFF(w2.RecordDate, w1.RecordDate) = 1`), and the condition that the new row's temperature is higher than the previous row (`w2.Temperature > w1.Temperature`) i.e.

```
SELECT *
FROM Weather w1
JOIN Weather w2 ON DATEDIFF(w2.RecordDate, w1.RecordDate) = 1
               AND w2.Temperature > w1.Temperature
```

If you look at all the output values from that query you can see that for each row, the `RecordDate` values for `w2` are one day later than `w1`, and the temperature for `w2` is higher than that for `w1`:

```
Id  RecordDate          Temperature Id  RecordDate          Temperature
1   2015-01-01 00:00:00 10          2   2015-01-02 00:00:00 25
3   2015-01-03 00:00:00 20          4   2015-01-04 00:00:00 30
```

So from that result it is just a question of selecting only the `w2.Id` values i.e.

```
SELECT w2.Id AS Id
FROM Weather w1
JOIN Weather w2 ON DATEDIFF(w2.RecordDate, w1.RecordDate) = 1
               AND w2.Temperature > w1.Temperature
```

Output

```
Id
2
4
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/h5gefcvfKycQ5Zg3Pgpi9o/0)

Answer (score 1):

The `JOIN` condition is connecting one row's data to the previous row.  I think this would be more obvious using date arithmetic:

```
SELECT w.id
FROM weather w JOIN
     weather wprev
     ON wprev.date = w.date - interval 1 day
WHERE w.Temperature > wprev.Temperature;
```

This might even be able to make use of an index on `(date)`.

That said, the more obvious solution is `lag()` -- and that is what you should be learning:

```
select w.*
from (select w.*,
             lag(temperature) over (order by date) as prev_temperature
      from weather w
     ) w
where prev_temperature < temperature;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is mine solution:

```
SELECT table1.Id as 'Id'
FROM Weather as table1
INNER JOIN Weather as table2
ON datediff(table1.RecordDate, table2.RecordDate) = 1
and table1.Temperature> table2.Temperature;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried using the `LAG()` Window function. Here is my solution:

```sql
with base as (
  select *,
  lag(temperature)over(order by recordDate) as previous_temp,
  lag(recordDate) OVER (ORDER BY recordDate) AS Prev,
  DATE_SUB(recordDate, INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS OneDayEarlier
  from Weather 
)
select id 
from base
where Prev = OneDayEarlier
      and temperature > previous_temp
```